# Trying to figure out what heights the ceiling needs to be to get an average height of 7 feet but maintain the normal height of ceiling at 8 feet

Tags: html

I have an attic build I would like to finish with an average height of 7 feet.  Anything less than 7 feet needs to be against the walls but closets need to be at least 7 feet high.  Areas around windows can be as low as 5 feet up to 3 feet out.  Areas close to walls can be as low as 5 feet.  Want as much area as possible at 8 ft.
Can someone show me how to calculate this?  Total sq/ft of rooms are 698 sq/ft.
[image: measurements of rooms]

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not an expert over here but you might get a faster respond on a diffrent forum or with a diffrent tag instead of html :P

Comment: You are right. But please, since this is not an answer, use the question comments section and not the answers section.

Comment: Yeah I would love to but it said that i need atleast 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: Wasn’t sure how to and there were no ‘height measurements’ options.  If I can I will......